# Why are my Button views in my horizontal LinearLayout set to a fixed width regardless of how I change the padding?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Why is my Button view in my LinearLayout set to a fixed width regardless of how I change the padding? I have my layout_width and height set to wrap_content, and I have played around with the padding from 0dp to 24dp, but the width of my + and - buttons do not change, as can be seen.

here is my xml code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="#E0E0E0"
            android:onClick="decrement"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="#E0E0E0"
            android:onClick="increment"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$0"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ORDER"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

as can be seen, my + and - buttons should have no width, but the display, and my phone shows otherwise...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOhKo.jpg thats the link to my display

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Usun

Comment: set height of linear layout to match_parent

Comment: It doest show that much width as in image on my machine

Comment: This didn't work... it just pushed the other views in my first viewgroup out of the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the width of the buttons use layout_width=100dp(Or any size you wish) as follows:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        />
```

Or you can use padding this way (paddingLeft and paddingRight):

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:paddingRight="42dp"
        android:paddingLeft="42dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        />
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried all the solutions and this seems to be my best bet. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Always welcome. If the answer was really helpful, you can approve the answer. So that it can be useful to others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    <!--android:padding="?yourpaddingdp"-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:onClick="increment"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    <!--android:padding="?yourpaddingdp"-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the linearlayout containing the buttons and textview with following:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:onClick="decrement"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:onClick="increment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry i have poor English.
Because the Button has minWidth, and you only set "+" in it,if you set "+++++" in
 it, the width will be change。

Answer (score 0):

It is because your button has width of `"wrap_content"` and content is so small. You can give it a specific width to make it wider. you can try 50dp or whatever you need. BTW are you doing udacity building layouts? It's a good course.

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="-"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:background="#E0E0E0"
android:onClick="decrement"/>
```

Comment: Yes I am! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your question is concerned

> "Why is my Button view in my LinearLayout set to a fixed width?"

the answer is that :

> "Button is a view and its minHeight is set to 48dip by default"

So either you can set `minWidth` accordingly or you can also use @Sayalee Pote's answer.